# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when calling dll from Pythonnet

Tags: python, dll, python.net

I am working on Pythonnet in Pycharm and calling C# dll from the python code, but getting error below while calling method.

Below is code

```
from pythonnet import load
load("coreclr")

import platform
print(platform.architecture())
import clr
from System import *
from Microsoft import *

clr.AddReference("dll/dllname2")
from dllname import classname

var1 = String("test")
var2 = String("test")


obj: object = Class()
msg =(obj.MethodName(String(""),String("")))
```

Exception

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
```

Please help. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Simply loading coreclr is not enough if you have any dependencies. You need to provide a [.runtimeconfig.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/)